# Array can't be coerced into Integer (TypeError)

Tags: arrays, ruby

I was able to get this code working locally but it fails in hacker rank
I've tried many combinations but must be missing something.
I don't understand why `sum += x` give the array error based on the output

I get this error:

solution.rb:24:in `+': Array can't be coerced into Integer (TypeError)

```
  def diagonalDifference(arr)
    arr.each do |e|
      p e
    end
    the_arr = arr.dup
    left_to_right(3, the_arr)
  end

  def left_to_right(the_size, the_data)
    sum = 0
    (0..the_size-1).each do |diagonal|
      this_value = (the_size * diagonal) + diagonal
      p "v= " + this_value.to_s
      x = the_data[this_value]
      p "this_sum= " + x.to_s
      sum += x  # <-- line 24
    end
    sum
  end

Debug output
[11, 2, 4]
[4, 5, 6]
[10, 8, -12]
"v= 0"
"this_sum= [[11, 2, 4], [4, 5, 6], [10, 8, -12]]"


arr would be a value such as [1,2,3,9,8,7,-4,-5,-4]
```

Seems like the issue relates to

```
the_data[this_value]
```

instead of getting a value I seem to get an array perhaps ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the input is a matrix like `[[11, 2, 4], [4, 5, 6], [10, 8, -12]]`

I guess you want to change the matrix to an array before pass to `left_to_right`. you can use `flatten`

```rb
def diagonalDifference(arr)
    arr.each do |e|
      p e
    end
    the_arr = arr.flatten
    left_to_right(3, the_arr)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be [this one](http://allhackerranksolutions.blogspot.com/2016/02/diagonal-difference-hacker-rank-solution.html).

One could compute the desired value as follows.

```
def diagonal_difference(arr)
 (arr.each_index.sum { |i| arr[i][i] - arr[i][-i-1]}).abs
end
```

```
arr = [
  [11, 2,   4],
  [ 4, 5,   6],
  [10, 8, -12]
]
```

```
diagonal_difference(arr)
  #=> 15
```